# Как поставить jQuery-событие на включение YouTube-видео?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, youtube-api

Нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку воспроизведения видео, исчезала синяя плашка снизу.

[image: Нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку воспроизведения видео, исчезала синяя плашка снизу.]

Answer (score 1):

js

```
var blueBlock = document.getElementById('blueBlock');

document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(event.target.id == 'video' || event.target.parent.id == 'video') {
        blueBlock.style.display = 'none';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<script>
    $('.video-block').click(function(){
        $(".blue-block").toggleClass("hide")
    });
</script>
```

css

```
.hide {display:none;}
```

Comment: так не срабатывает

Comment: @АлександрТимофеев,  приведите пример вашего кода..